# How do I stop the bees from attacking?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In the Deep Woods, I am trying to cross a rope. That's hard enough on its own but now there are bees flying at me and I can't seem to get them to leave me alone without falling off of the rope. How do I make them go away?

Comment: So what you're trying to say is, ["Aaaaa! Aaaaaa! I'm covered in beeeeeees!"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xs-tl6GBOBo)?

Comment: One option you might want to try would be to go back to the `Skyloft` and buy a `Bug Catching Net` from `Beedle`. With that go back there and swipe up all the hornets. It will take a little while for the next wave of hornets to attack you again. That might be enough time for you to cross the rope.

Comment: http://www.lesspopmorefizz.com/img/Bees.gif

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should try taking the hive down with the slingshot before engaging the rope and running like mad because the bees are going to go after you anyway. You'll have a clear path to cross the rope after that.

Apparently, you can also walk calmly and the bees will lose interest fairly quickly.

Comment: And don't forget to pick up the Hornet Larvae (http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Hornet_Larvae) where the hive hits the ground, before it expires.

Comment: True, except in this particular situation, the hive is going to fall down in the abyss, so no larvae when you're using the slingshot to cross the rope in the Deep Woods.

Answer (score 3):

May not be helpful for the situation you described, but in general for the bees just bring out your bug net and scoop them all up. Ain't no bees attacking you if you catch them all!

Comment: I see another Jeff already answered this in a comment

Comment: That's fine that you answered it. It's just that in this particular case, using the net might not be so successful since there isn't any ground nearby the draw them out where you can use your net.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I used the beetle to save slingshot ammo,

a little bump and it falls off into the abyss.

Once you get the beetle upgrade you can drop a whole hive on some unsuspecting moblins.

Comment: BTW the beetle upgrade comes from the desert on the way to the third temple not at the scrap shop

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem, but I found a solution.  Take out your slingshot and shoot the bees' nest down and run for your life!  When the bees go away you can come back and climb the rope.  :)

btw if u can shoot faaar far away from it the bees dont even chase you but u have to be almost aornd the corner

Comment: -1: This is what the top-voted and accepted answer suggests, except not as well-written.